# Set the background colour of a Layout view to a gradient in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I specify that the background "colour" of a Android layout view element should be a gradient (at a specific angle) ?

I wish to specify this in the XML, i.e. not at runtime. Preferably as a style I can apply to any layout I wish with the `style` property?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

create `gradient.xml` in `/res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="45"/>    
</shape>
```

and in your `main.xml` layout file in `/res/layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    >   
</LinearLayout>
```

you can specify the angle by replacing the `android:angle` value and start/end colour by replacing `android:startColor` and `android:endColor`

Comment: can we change xml gradient value at runtime

Answer (score 10):

You can use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#A1A1A1" 
              android:centerColor="#BDBDBD"
              android:endColor="#A4A4A4" 
              android:angle="-90" />
</shape>
```

to build a gradient (You choose the colors you like ). Place this in drawable and voila you got your own shape to use as background: `android:background="@drawable/the_name_of_your_xml"`

Answer (score 5):

This is how I have set gradient style. Hope this helps. But I have used it for textview. Maybe you have to make some changes to fit to your layout background.

```
            Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 20, new int[] {
            Color.WHITE, getResources().getColor(//some color),
            getResources().getColor(//some color), Color.WHITE },
            new float[] {  0.25f,0.50f,0.75f, 1 }, TileMode.CLAMP);
            textview.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

Comment: although he mentioned in the question that he would like to have a xml-solution, not a runtime one