# what is different between setColorSchemeColors(int... colors) and setColorSchemeResources(int... colorResIds) and setColorScheme(int... colors)?

Tags: android

in android doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setColorSchemeColors(int...)
 for set color schema have three methods
what is difference between 3 methods?

```
setColorScheme(int... colors)
setColorSchemeColors(int... colors)
setColorSchemeResources(int... colorResIds)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the API docs, I can see that `setColorScheme` is deprecated in favour of `setColorSchemeResources`. So forget that first one.

The different between `setColorSchemeColors` and `setColorSchemeResources` is that the former takes colour values as the parameters and the latter takes resource IDs.

So.

- `setColorScheme` - do not use this
- `setColorSchemeColors` - use this when setting the specific colour values
- `setColorSchemeResources` - use this when setting resource references to colours.

Comment: So , can I set drawable shape with resourceId?! I want set gradient
! how I can do this?!

Comment: These colours are for the animated bar when refreshing the view. e.g. http://antonioleiva.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/SwipeRefreshLayout.gif  See this blog for more human-readable info: http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

Comment: is there any way to set gradient for schema color?!

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388809/set-the-background-colour-of-a-layout-view-to-a-gradient-in-android

Comment: I created drawable gradient and setColorSchemeResources(drawableID)
but I get error!!why?!