# Android Studio Layout Editor- How can I add gradient on stroke

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add gradient function on stroke(button and textview), but I don't know how to code it.

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388809/set-the-background-colour-of-a-layout-view-to-a-gradient-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the background colour of a Layout view to a gradient in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388809/set-the-background-colour-of-a-layout-view-to-a-gradient-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

here an example for you that may help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="360"
            android:centerColor="#e95c12"
            android:endColor="#ff00b4"
            android:gradientRadius="360"
            android:startColor="#006342"
            android:type="sweep" />

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#ff217a00" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="20dp"
    android:left="20dp"
    android:right="20dp"
    android:top="20dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to res --> drawable (right click) --> New ---> Drawable resource file. Name your file name anything you like and click OK. When the resource file layout opens, you can copy and paste the codes below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape= "rectangle" >

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#EF4444"/>

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#000000"/>

        <corners
            android:radius="3dp"/>

        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#1B34D8"
            android:endColor="#D8A91B"
            android:angle="270"/>

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#008577"/>

        <corners
            android:radius="3dp"/>

        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Then add the codes below to your Button or TextView.

```
android: background="@drawable/your_resource_file_name"
```

Comment: Its better to understand if you can properly write the correct code with correct formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<stroke android:color="@color/blue"
    android:width="1dp">
    <gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#4e5eff"
    android:startColor="#2686ff" />
</stroke>

<corners android:radius="30dp"/>
```